# subscript notation in conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation, random-variables

$X$ and $Y$ are two discrete random variables with joint p.m.f $p_{XY}$ such that $p_{XY}(x_i,y_j) = P(X=x_i, Y=y_i)$.

I came across a notation that refers to $p_{X}(x|y)$. How do I express it in the form of $p_{XY}$?

Does $p_{X}(x|y) = \sum\limits_{y_j} p_{XY} (X = x, Y = y_j)$?

What is $p_{Y}(x|y)$ then? How does subscript of $p$ affect the meaning?

Comment: Surely MathStackExchange has a standard wikified answer for the seemingly endless stream of "what does this conditional probability notation mean?"

Comment: @EricTowers sorry, can't find anything directly related.

Comment: What is your source for the notation $p_X(x|y)$?

Comment: @Did see eq. 3.3 here http://books.google.com/books?id=EwyqfWv24l8C&lpg=PP1&dq=techniques%20for%20noise%20robustness&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=techniques%20for%20noise%20robustness&f=false

Comment: Thanks. Note that this is hardly a *probability theory* textbook.

Comment: @Did no it isn't. But how do I understand what the author is saying using standard notation?

Comment: You could start by reading my answer...

Comment: @Did I did, do you mean to say author should have used $X|C$ in the subscript?

Comment: If X and C are the relevant random variables, then yes, definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}\qquad p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_X(x)}$$