# Understanding the conditional entropy derivation

Tags: statistics, information-theory, expected-value

[This lecture on slide 5](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~iftachh/Courses/Info/Fall14/Printouts/Lesson2_h.pdf), has the following derivation which I don't understand their notation changes:

let $(X,Y) \sim p$.

For $x\in Supp(X)$ the random variable $Y|X=x$ is well defined.

**Q1: Why is the above relevant?**

Continues... let $p_x$ & $p_{Y|X}$ be marginals induced by p.

$$H(Y|X) = \sum_{x \in X}p_x(x) H(Y|X=x)$$

Q2: isn't the $p_x(x)$ notation redundant? could it just be  left as $p(x)$?

$$=-\sum_{x \in X} p_x(x) \sum_{y \in Y} p_{Y|X}(Y|X) log p_{Y|X}(y|x)$$

Q3: same question... isn't $p_{Y|X}$ redundant also? ie: could just be $p(Y|X)$

$$=-\sum_{x \in X, y \in Y} p(x,y)log p_{Y|X}(y|x) \\
= -E_{(X,Y)} log p_{Y|X}(y|x)$$

Q4: How can they rewrite $-\sum_{x \in X, y \in Y} p(x,y)$ as $E_{(X,Y)}$? Doesn't expectation require something like: $-\sum_{x \in X, y \in Y} p(x,y)f(x,y)$? (ie: a probability times a function)?

Comment: leonbloy has answered your questions. Let me join you in griping a little - it is good style to mention the distributions involved explicitly with subscripts, this usually helps with clarity (not always, though. Depends on how dense the expressions are). However, there are two basic flaws with the writing in the slide - firstly, they should have written $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Writing $p(x,y)$ is inconsistent with the rest of the notation ($p_X, p_{X|Y}$). Secondly, the final expression $\mathbb{E}_{(X,Y) \sim p}[\log p_{X|Y}(X|Y)]$ is confusing - the...

Comment: (contd.)  subscript in $p_{X|Y}$ is meant to indicate the function that we're taking expectation of, but it is the same as the random variables - a most discombobulating notation, especially the first few times one sees it. I'd have preferred it if they used a dummy variable for the RVs in the final expectation. Unfortunately, both these abuses of notation are quite common in my reading, and worth getting used to just for sanity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: Why is the above relevant?

Not very relevant. If you are given a joint discrete probability function, that is always the case.

> Q2: isn't the $p_x(x)$ notation redundant? could it just be  left as $p(x)$?

No, if we want to be precise and rigorous. True, we often write $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ to denote the (marginal) probabilities of $X$ and $Y$, but that's sloppy notation. See, in math, when we write $f(x)$ the function is identified by the letter $f$ , $x$ is just a dumb variable (and so, if $f(x)=x^2$ then $f(y) = y^2$ and $f(x+1) =(x+1)^2$ so on: if we reuse $f()$, then we understand that it's *the same function* , it's only its argument what changes; if we want to write a different function, we use another letter, say $g()$ ). Now, in my example above, we'd like to keep using the letter $p$ (or $f$ if we speak of densities), then to denote that they are different functions we write a subscript, so that $p_X()$ and $p_Y()$ (read them as a double letter) are different functions.

True, $p_X()$ will normallly be evaluated in values of the random variable $X$ (which we denote conventionally by $x$). But that's not necessary, nor enough to identify the functions. Suppose I ask you: write down the probability of $X$ taking the value $x=3$: you would write $p(x)$ evaluated at $3$, which you must write $p(3)$. But then you cannot distinguish it with the probability of $Y$ taking the value $y=3$. With the correct notation, there is no confussion: $p_X(3)$ and $p_Y(3)$.

See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102386/different-notations-of-probability/2102403#2102403).

> Q3: same question... isn't $p_{Y|X}$ redundant also? ie: could just be $p(Y|X)$

Same answer. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836889/subscript-notation-in-conditional-probability).

> Q4: How can they rewrite $-\sum_{x \in X, y \in Y} p(x,y)$ as $E_{(X,Y)}$? Doesn't expectation require something like: $-\sum_{x \in X, y \in Y} p(x,y)f(x,y)$? (ie: a probability times a function)?

Exactly. The expectation of something is the summation of the probability multiplied by that something. In one variable: $E[g(X)]  = \sum_x g(x) p_X(x) $

Hence

$$ E [ -\log(p_X(X))] = \sum_x \underbrace{(- \log(p_X(x)))}_\text{g(x)} \, p_X(x)=- \sum_x \log(p_X(x)) p_X(x)$$

The formula you wrote is just the same in two variables.